# How to access command prompt when starting node.js server?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have a node.js server set up and would like to send something to the command prompt on start up (because I couldn't figure out how to do it when the server was already running).

Do I do this from the server.js file? And what would the code look like?

I currently have this argument, which works when I normally access the windows command prompt on my own:

C:\Users\path\python.exe C:\Users\path\test.py

Server.js:

```
const exec= require("child_process").exec;
const pythonProcess = 
exec("C:/Users/myPath/python.exe",
["C:/Users/myPath/test.py"]);
```

Everything compiles, and the server starts, but there is no evidence that the python file has been run. (When it normally runs, there is a document saved on my desktop) Am I doing something wrong?

Thank You.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: There are a few options here. IMO the most beginner friendly API is `exec`: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

...and yes, put that in your `server.js` file, or whatever file you are passing to node on startup.

Comment: @SuperStormer added the minimal reproducible example for you

Comment: Instead of executing `python.exe`, have you consider using a node package that is intended for this purpose?  I have not tried this myself, but a quick search of npm shows [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) and [python](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python) packages.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Yes I have tried that

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do? You're in Node, a general purpose standard library API built on top of JavaScript, capable of doing basically everything python can do. Why are you trying to run a python script instead of doing whatever that (presumably small) script does using Node itself?

Comment: @JamesDean - So you tried that and... what happened?   Also, you might want to review [the docs for `child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).  Note that `exec` doesn't take an array as its second parameter.  You also aren't providing a callback.  Maybe you meant `execFileSync`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to spawn a python process from a node process. You probably want to use Node's `child_process.spawn()` instead of `child_process.exec()`. Node's `child_process.exec()` is

1. asynchronous, and
2. buffer `stdout` and `stderr`, so you won't see any of their output until the callback on the `exec()` is invoked when the child process exits... and since you haven't given it a callback, you'll never see it.

Try something like this:

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process') ;

const python = '.../python.exe' ;
const argv = [
  '.../test.py',
] ;

const child = childProcess.spawn( python, argv, {
  detached: false,
  stdio: [
    'inherit', // inherit STDIN  from the parent process
    'inherit', // inherit STDOUT from the parent process
    'inherit', // inherit STDERR from the parent process
  ],
  shell: false,
}) ;

child.on('error', ( err ) => {
  console.log(`${python}: ${err.stack}`) ;
}) ;

child.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
  console.log(`${python}: exited with exit code ${code}, signal '${signal}'`) ;
}) ;
```

But if all you're trying to do here is kick off a python program... why don't you do that via a shell script (on Windows, either a "batch" file (`*.cmd`) file or a Powershell script (`*.ps`)?

Comment: This is good, so I'll accept it, but my partners have decided it is essential for this to work either on click of a button or when refreshing the page. In other words I have to make it work while the server is already running. Thank you though.